# qt project cannot find plugin - set via importPaths from qmlproject file?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

A customer provided a QML project v1.1 from Qt Creator 2.6.1 and it cannot find an import path of one of the plugins:

I set it to:

```
importPaths: [ "plugins/com/myCustomer/hmiframework"]
```

this is the directory of the .dll files, but the qml files are not finding the libs.

I am getting this error on the import code:

```
 import com.myCustomer.hmiframework 1.0
```

here is the error:

```
Error while loading project file C:/Users/elswick/Documents/Customers/myCustomer/docs/project/name/project.qmlproject.
file:///C:/Users/elswick/Documents/Customers/myCustomer/project/name/project.qmlproject:20 Property value set multiple times
```

not sure where to go from here.  The error shown when I select Design is this:

```
QML module not found

Import paths:
C:/Users/elswick/Documents/Customers/myCustomer/docs/project/name/plugins/com/myCustomer/hmiframework

For qmake projects, use the QML_IMPORT_PATH variable to add import paths.
for qmlproject projects, use the importPaths property to add import paths. (2:1)
```

thanks.

Comment: Sorry I have the same problem. How are you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

i think there is an error in your project at (or around) line 20 where a *property value is set multiple times*. this means, that you have to fix this error, before `qtcreator` can load the module.